# how to know if some data already exist on device - disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux

how to know if some data already exist on device - disk

The simple way to check if disk include filesystem is to do:

```
 mount /grid/sdb /mnt
```

and if sdb or other /dev/sdx have file-system then mount will be succeeded, if not ... probably file system exists!

but this is ugly way to check that..

what the other elegant alternative to check file-system on disk?

my target is to check if file-system already configured on disk's as /dev/sdb - /dev/sdx

Comment: `blkid` / `lsblk -f`

Comment: do you mean to do for example - blkid | grep sdx , and if it match then we know for sure that filesystem created ?      ( can you please write your solution as well .......................... )

Comment: You don't need grep. You can pass a specific drive to either of the commands.

Comment: you mean to run this - for example - blkid /dev/sdg

Comment: in any case fs not created on disk it will give standard output diff from 0

Comment: If there's no recognized filesystem signatures found on the partition, they will not show a filesystem type. Output of lsblk -f might be easier to read since it outputs in columns, and usually, unlike blkid, it doesn't need root (though it needs udev instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `parted -l` to list partitions (and filesystems). In case you are interested in damaged or partially wiped filesystems you can use recovery tools such as [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: so I guess - you mean to run this - parted -l | grep "unrecognised disk label" and if filesystem not create it will bring the disk that match the - "unrecognised disk label"

Comment: if you want only to see details for a single disk, you can use `parted /dev/sdX print`.